# When the mobile is in airplane mode, react-native-vector-icons stop waking

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-vector-icons

So I have been having a little problem, I am using expo together with `react-native-vector-icons` to render some icons.

The problem is that when the mobile is in airplane mode, `react-native-vector-icons` stop waking.

Now This is a problem and because I am using different themes, size, color etc and there to many icons, I do not want to include those icons in bundle.

I have been thinking of downloading those icons as `png` and saving it in some directory the first time the app starts, so it could be loaded offline.

The problem is I am using `expo bare` and I cannot use `Icon.getImageSource` in expo.

Is there any other alternative/way I could do what I want?

Here is my current code that is working when there is internet.

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import { StyleProp, TextStyle } from 'react-native'
import { ThemeContext } from './theme/ThemeProvider';
import AntDesign from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign'
import MaterialCommunityIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons'
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo'
import Feather from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather'
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5'
import FontAwesome from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome'
import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto'
import EvilIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons'
import Filememo from '../attributes/FileMemo'
import serviceTempData from '../services/ServiceOperations';
import { ImageSource } from 'react-native-vector-icons/Icon';


const IconTypeArray = {
    AntDesign,
    MaterialCommunityIcons,
    Ionicons,
    MaterialIcons,
    Entypo,
    Feather,
    Fontisto,
    FontAwesome5,
    FontAwesome,
    EvilIcons
} as any;

type ElementType = "AntDesign" | "MaterialCommunityIcons" | "Ionicons" | "MaterialIcons" | "Entypo" | "Feather" | "FontAwesome5" | "FontAwesome" | "Fontisto" | "EvilIcons";


export default (props: { type: ElementType, name: string, size?: number, color?: string, style?: StyleProp<TextStyle> }) => {
    const themeContext = React.useContext(ThemeContext);
    const Icon = IconTypeArray[props.type];
    const pType = { ...props } as any;

    delete pType.type;
    if (pType.color === undefined)
        pType.color = themeContext.themeStyle().color;
    if (pType.size == undefined)
        pType.size = themeContext.iconSize;
    return (
        <Icon {...pType} />
    )
}
```

and using it is as simple as

```js
<Icon type="Ionicons" name='md-reload-circle' size={20} color="red" />
```

Comment: As far as I know, these are bundled. Can you try running a bundle analyzer & check if they are bundled or not?

Comment: the fonts are boundled but the library need to create an URL to present the svg and without internet, the font wont show upp. its a known problem the library has so its nothing new.

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom component to resolve this issue?

Comment: Been thinking of doing that but I am not an android developer and need a little help doing that,

Comment: I could write one real quick for you. So, if I'm following correctly, you need a pressable component that has an image inside of it?

Comment: a components that extract an image from 'react-native-vector-icons'

Comment: Kk, and are you looking to download the pngs of the icons?

Comment: yes so it could be saved to a local folder.